# Aggregate by sub-category, then order by category in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to aggregate (count) data by sub-category but I need them to be ordered based on overall category count in descending order?

For example, my column headers are:

```
tbl (table name)
singularity_id (key)
product_cat (category)
consumption_location (sub-category)
```

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT 
    product_cat, consumption_location, COUNT(DISTINCT singularity_id) as count
FROM 
    tbl
GROUP BY 
    product_cat, consumption_location
ORDER BY 
    product_cat, consumption_location, count DESC;
```

This groups product_cat and consumption_location but does not order by product_cat count desc.

So my data currently looks like this, based on my query:

```
product_cat | consumption_location | count  
------------+----------------------+--------
Fruit Juice | Store                |  200  
Fruit Juice | Home                 |  600  
Soft Drink  | Store                | 1200  
Soft Drink  | Home                 |  100  
Water       | Store                |  400  
Water       | Home                 |  500
```

What I want is:

```
product_cat | consumption_location | count  
------------+----------------------+--------
Soft Drink  | Store                | 1200  
Soft Drink  | Home                 |  100  
Water       | Store                |  400  
Water       | Home                 |  500  
Fruit Juice | Store                |  200  
Fruit Juice | Home                 |  600
```

Since Soft Drink has the most overall entries, followed by Water, then Fruit Juice.

Comment: Can you show us your expected output with the ordering you expect?

Comment: the count you are referencing is a count of singularity_id, not count of product_cat. try adding another count column in the select statement such as COUNT(product_cat) as count2 and then add count2 to the order by clause. let me know what happens

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
So my data currently looks like this, based on my query:

product_cat | consumption_location | count
----- | ----- | -----
Fruit Juice | Store | 200
Fruit Juice | Home | 600
Soft Drink | Store | 1200
Soft Drink | Home | 100
Water | Store | 400
Water | Home | 500

What I want is:

product_cat | consumption_location | count
----- | ----- | -----
Soft Drink | Store | 1200
Soft Drink | Home | 100
Water | Store | 400
Water | Home | 500
Fruit Juice | Store | 200
Fruit Juice | Home | 600

Since Soft Drink has the most overall entries, followed by Water, then Fruit Juice.

Comment: I don't follow the logic which arrives at the ordering in your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
with temptbl as
    (select  distinct product_cat, consumption_location,
        count(SINGULARITY_ID) over (partition by product_cat) cntcat ,
        count(SINGULARITY_ID) over (partition by 
        product_cat,consumption_location) as cntsub 
     from t2  order by cntcat desc
    )
select product_cat ,consumption_location , cntsub from temptbl ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a temp table you can add in a count for the partition by for a "total"

```
SELECT 
product_cat, consumption_location, COUNT(DISTINCT singularity_id) as count,
count(*) over (partition by product_cat) as total
FROM 
tbl
GROUP BY 
product_cat, consumption_location
ORDER BY 
total Desc, product_cat, consumption_location
```

but you can leave out the total completely from the select statement and add it in the order by since it's an aggregate

```
SELECT 
product_cat, consumption_location, COUNT(DISTINCT singularity_id) as count
FROM 
tbl
GROUP BY 
product_cat, consumption_location
ORDER BY 
count(*) over (partition by product_cat) Desc, consumption_location
```

This should get you what you need in your sample though I'm not sure why you have the store at the top always. So I am only ordering it by these two the other fields don't seem to matter in your example only the final total then consumption_location seems to be ascending after the grand total